# How to filter file paths then use the resulting paths

Tags: file, file-io, rust, filepath

I trying to get a list of mp3 from a  directory.

```
let dir_paths = fs::read_dir(&Path::new("some_directory")).unwrap();

let paths = dir_paths.filter(|x| match x.unwrap().path().extension() {
    None => true,
    Some(ext) => ext == "mp3"
});
```

The Error Message

```
src/main.rs:27:48: 27:49 error: cannot move out of borrowed content
src/main.rs:27     let paths = dir_paths.filter(|ref x| match x.unwrap().path().extension() {
                                                              ^
```

I tried replacing `|x|` with `|ref x|` but got the same error message.  What is correct way of doing this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a look at the documentation for [`Result::unwrap`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap):

> ```
> fn unwrap(self) -> T
> ```
>
> Unwraps a result, yielding the content of an Ok.

Note how it takes `self`? That means that the option will be consumed. However, your iterator is passing the closure a `&Result<T, _>`. You can't take ownership of the `Option` because it is borrowed.

The shortest fix is to get an `Result<&T, _>` instead, using [`as_ref`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/result/enum.Result.html#method.as_ref):

```
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let dir_paths = fs::read_dir("/").unwrap();

    let paths = dir_paths.filter(|x| match x.as_ref().unwrap().path().extension() {
        None => true,
        Some(ext) => ext == "mp3"
    });
}
```

Although I might choose to write it as

```
use std::fs;
use std::ffi::OsStr;

fn main() {
    let dir_paths = fs::read_dir("/").unwrap();

    dir_paths
        .filter_map(|x| x.ok())
        .filter(|x| x.path().extension().and_then(OsStr::to_str) == Some("mp3"));
}
```

There's some less unwraps - we just ignore any failed `DirEntry`s. That's up to your error handling strategy though.

Comment: Your version is much nicer